# include or extend in uml use case diagram

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

The purpose of the application is a displaying a dashboard. I have several actions/use cases like:

- Login (User/Admin)
- Show Dashboard 01(User)
- Show Dasboard 02 (User)
- Show Dasboard 03 (User)
- Show Dasboard 04 (User)
- Filter Data (User)
- Manage Permission (Admin)
- Manage Interfaces (Admin)
- Manage Data sources (Admin)
- Commenting (User)

My question is which connection exists to the several Dasboards or should it be like one use case ‘show dashboards’ ?

Include or Extend?

[image]

Comment: In your question you explain HOW you want to provide some features to the users, but not WHY the user wants to use your system.  Moreover it is not clear if the user MUST go from A to D, if the use CAN go directly to D without passing through A, or if the user can go to A but MAY decide to stay there and not pursue the journey? Lastly, could you clarify why you think you need a use-case?

Comment: It would be more easy to answer if you provided your UC diagram.

Comment: I have updated my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `User`, I see the following use-case:

- `Get an overview of the situation`

That's all:  the dashboards and filtering are only means that you propose to address the ends.  The login is not a use-case either: it's also  a mean to address the constraints that only authorised users can access the information. Single sign on (SSO) or facial identification could be alternatives.

Use-cases are not meant to design user interface. There are much better techniques for that.   Use-cases are not features either. User-stories are very suitable for describing features (e.g. "As a user I want to filter data in the dashboard for the purpose of finding more specific insights").  You'd have dozens, if not hundreds of user-stories, but only a few use-cases since these are meant to show the big picture.

If you want to model something action oriented (show this, filter that, ...)  or some sequence (first login, then move to dahsboard 01, then ....) you could consider an activity diagram.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I saw some "use case diagrams" in the web and tried to adapt some patterns which could be matching for my use case. I will have a look on activity diagramm, I think it allows a more detailed description of the process.

Comment: I can recommend Bittner/Spence about use case modeling. For me the best read you can get on that topic.

Comment: @UdoGniß if the answer helped to solve your problem, don't forget to accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Neither. You're not mentioning use case nor use case dependency but what seems to be systems dependency.

Depending on what you want to depict either each of the sites is considered a separate system or all those sites are just modules of one system.

In the former case if you are trying to show use cases of A, whatever use case requires pages B, C or D they will have to reach out to separate system, that is B. Since it is a separate system it will be an Actor for A linked to respective use case(s)

In the latter case, the use case offered to the user doesn't present internal implementation. It doesn't matter how many internal modules it has to use, it is always just a single use case.

Now, if you are trying to show that dependency in a more precise manner, it should not happen on the Use Case diagram. Instead the recommended option is usually Sequence Diagram with few other alternatives available (Communication Diagram and Activity Diagram being the most often occurring supplements).

Comment: Okay thank you for your advise. So if we want to make use of use case diagram we need to keep it generally and in terms of the use case. So lets say my use case is a dashboard application where the user has the ability to go through the different cases.

- login
- show dashboard (here we have different dashboards/layers like A,B,C,D) 
- comment on dashboard
- manage permission 
- manage data source 

Do you think i can still use a use case diagramm for this use case?

Comment: When you write:  "In the latter case, the use case offered to the user doesn't present internal implementation", do you mean the current representation doesn't show the internal implementation, or that the representation should not show the internal implementation?  - [RFC 2119](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119)

Comment: @Christophe, I mean it should not show the internal implementation.