# Activity Diagram vs Use-case diagram

Tags: uml, use-case, activity-diagram, use-case-diagram

I'm trying to model the behavior of a dashboard system, and more precisely how a user could navigate between the different features that are offered.

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70278546/3723423) I have explored use-case diagrams for this purpose.  But it turned out that these are not well suited for user navigation and sequence of interactions.  I therefore have decided to keep my use case simple as in the answer to that question.

I have now created an activity diagram for my use case. But I am new to the activity diagrams, and am not sure that it represents the intended flow correctly  (i.e. user logs in, choses to go to the dashboards and views the first dashboard, then may drill down in more detailed dashboards and filter the data that is viewed; unregistererd users have first to go through a registration process with the system administrator).

Here the result:

[image: Updated AC-Diagram]

I already know I should insert the different roles (user/admin)   but is this diagram reflecting the described flow or are there obvious mistakes?

Comment: No. It's incorrect. The Password action top middle is stuck. Please refrain from general reviews. Only ask specific questions here.

Comment: @qwerty_so do you mean the Login and the Insert … password (which both vave 2 incoming flows) ?

Comment: @Christophe Yes. Neglecting that the left arrow is just plain wrong.

Comment: I've slightly edited your question.  General diagram review questions are out of scope.  So I've narrowed it down, to make it answerable and general enough to be useful for other people having similar issues. I hope you can agree with the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram roughly reprensents the intended design.

First some minor issues,  that you could quickly discover in [popular introductions to AD](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-activity-diagram/):

- The start and end should indeed be modelled with a black circle, and a black surrounded circle. But you already know.
- There are no diamonds with question as in traditional flow-charts: The diamonds stay small, and the condition is written as a guard between brackets on the top of the arrow.
- All arrows are simple arrows (no white triangle - that has a completely different meaning)

Then there is a more subtle issue:

- when there are two or more incoming arrows, the action only takes place when all the incomming arrows are simultaneously active.  This is why qwerty_so mentioned in the comment that `Login` and `Insert username and password` are stuck:  only one incoming arrow can be active, so the actions will never start.
- to solve this, you need to add merge-nodes: it's again diamonds, with several incoming arrows and one outgoing arrow.

Then it is not clear:  the filter data only applies to the last dashboard but will never result in any subsequent action ?

Then, do I undesrtant well:  as soon as the user comments a dashboard, he/she will leave the dashboard and go to the next ?

Finally,  you don't need to detail too much: you could have some simpler actions that combine several more detailed steps.  It's like zooming in/out.  If you put all the details in one diagram, it becomes very difficult to read.

Comment: The intended flow final is actually the flow start. That's just wrong. I'd say you can have the question marks inside. That's a decisive action. Though the guards outside should be bracketed. This kind of question is just too broad for here. Each question should be a single problem to discuss, not a bunch of starter questions.

Comment: @qwerty_so I agree with you in principle.  On the other hand,  there are soo many out there who ask about use-case and opt for an unsuitable functional decomposition against our advise, that I feel morally compelled to help the few that apply the advice.  I believe that despite the broad question,  this could inspire more people to use goal-oriented use-cases, when they see that there are better options for showing logins and sequencing actions.

Comment: Well, I understand your point. Maybe there should be some spot for review questions (isn't there one?). Definitely a "Is my xy-diagram correct" will not get a hit upon a specific question one tries to find at SO. In my POV SO is no tutorial point.

Comment: Okay! I have worked out the improvements. The filter data only applies to the last dashboard will result only on dashboard 4 (I have therefore connected the filter data action with the show dashboard 4 action). As soon as the user comments a dashboard, he/she will leave the dashboard and move to the next or leave the application completely. My goal was to show the complete process when the user opens the application and clicks through the different dashboards. Thats why I choose this way to zoom-in to the whole process. Of course, I could also show a more abstract process but it is meant so.

Comment: @Christophe I added the merge node (diamond) but I'm not quite sure, if this is applied right. I also changed the "Login" action and putted it before the "Insert.." action. I also added a new decision node in case if the user makes more than 3 attempts. Therefore I'm not sure if the "Insert.." is stuck because there are two incoming arrows.

Comment: @UdoGniß looks better!  Add a merge node before the Insert... action to get it right.   Also I don't understand the difference between "Login" action and "Insert unsername and password". Mayb eyou marge the two and consider that keying in is a subaction of login.

Comment: Thank you! Yes. Basically the Login and Insert username and password action is redundant. Therefore I removed the "Insert username and password" and only defined Login as the main action. I also added a merge node after "filter data" because there is two incoming arrows for "show dashboard 4" and that would cause a stuck in the process. Hope that is right! :D

Comment: @UdoGniß Indeed, I didnt spot the dahsboard 4.  Excellent!  I think that this demonstrates that you are about to master this kind of diagram ;-)